# HTML form: how to submit a value without showing it in the form?

Tags: html, forms

I have an HTML form that sends a food dish. For example,

`placeorder.com/order.php?id=STEAK`

I want to add another value and send

`placeorder.com/order.php?category=MEAT&id=STEAK`

But, I don't want the user to have to select `meat` anywhere, since this has been already decided.

I tried to tinker with the form target and include it from there, but it didn't work.

Is there some "hidden text box" to write the category to so that it gets posted, or is there another way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Please post your code so that I can add to it and show you.

Comment: Try adding a hidden input field, something like: ```<input type="hidden" name="category" value="MEAT" />```

Comment: Darn(!) I imagined that but did not think it would be so easy! thanks guys! Sorry...

Answer (score 3):

First, I just thought I'd mention that it's funny how the questions is phrased since you pretty much answered your own question:

> Is there some "hidden text box"

Anyway, yes:

You can use `type='hidden'`

I assume that you are already using a `GET` form so I will just include the input part:

```
<input name='category' type='hidden' value='MEAT'>
```

Comment: Its one of those moments... :(  Thanks and sorry!

Comment: you can "accept" an answer by clicking the green check below the vote count

Comment: I know, Im waiting for some minutes to pass. It says 3 more minutes to go.